# Go: converting string to float using strconv.ParseFloat returns 0

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
fmt.Print("room: width x length: ")

inStr, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
result := strings.Split(inStr, "x")

string1, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(result[0], 64)
string2, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(result[1], 64)
fmt.Print(string2)
```

At the last print statement, if i print `string1` it returns the right value, but if i try to print `string2` it returns 0, no matter what value i input to the console.

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
result := strings.Split(inStr, "x")
```

with

```
result := strings.Split(strings.TrimSpace(inStr), "x")
```

As string contains `\n` so your second array element contains it too.

Also I really suggest to look at error messages before posting such kind of questions. You could see `strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "23\n": invalid syntax` as result of next code

```
string2, err := strconv.ParseFloat(result[1], 64)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(e)
}
```